# Склонение названия организации

Tags: согласование, названия, приложение

Подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно: "продлить договор со Свердловской областной общественной благотворительной организацией пенсионеров и инвалидов - Ассоциация жертв политических репрессий" или "продлить договор со Свердловской областной общественной благотворительной организацией пенсионеров и инвалидов - Ассоциацией жертв политических репрессий" (Свердловская областная общественная благотворительная организация пенсионеров и инвалидов - Ассоциация жертв политических репрессий - так звучит полное наименование организации) И какое тут правило можно применить?

Comment: @Комитет, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

***Продлить договор со Свердловской областной общественной благотворительной организацией пенсионеров и инвалидов "Ассоциация жертв политических репрессий".*** Непосредственное название организации возьмите в кавычки, как положено, тогда склонять название в кавычках не нужно. Это приложение несогласованное.

Comment: А что, если придёт ответ: 
договор у нас заключался с организацией "Свердловская областная общественная благотворительная организация пенсионеров и инвалидов - Ассоциация жертв политических репрессий"? Видимо, так была зарегистрирована организация, в отличие, напр. от Тамбовской районной общественной организации «Ассоциация жертв политических репрессий». Нужно как минимум свериться с самим договором, если не склонять наименование в его официальной форме.

Comment: Тогда так: Договор у нас заключался с организацией <<Свердловская областная общественная благотворительная организация пенсионеров и инвалидов "Ассоциация жертв политических репрессий">>.

Comment: Да уж, использовать кавычки, если их не было в названии,  – это не очень удачная идея. Получается, что верен первый вариант из вопроса (Ассоциацией), где это название склоняется.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно авторскому праву в названии чего-либо буквы можно хоть вверх ногами ставить. Ну записали в названии ассоциацию с большой буквы, ну обошлись без кавычек — что за дело, важна суть. А грамматику в обращении с этим названием надо соблюдать. Если освободиться от второстепенных членов, то название будет выглядеть как Свердловская организация-Ассоциация. Вот с ней и надо заключать договор. Аналог: договор с лягушкой-Квакушкой. То есть правильным будет второй вариант у автора.